# Asterisk outbound_registration real time issue

Tags: asterisk, real-time

I configured an asterisk to run with realtime database. Every thing is working as expected, except the outbound_registration part, which was not running unless using pjsip.conf static file!

From asterisk Wiki, I read that outbound registration is not supported in real time, but that wiki page last updated on 2018!. So I wonder if it's supported now? and if so, what did I miss to make it work?

***My extconfig.conf is:***

```
ps_endpoints => mysql,asterisk
ps_auths => mysql,asterisk
ps_aors => mysql,asterisk
ps_contacts => mysql,asterisk
ps_domain_aliases => mysql,asterisk
ps_endpoint_id_ips => mysql,asterisk
ps_outbound_publishes => mysql,asterisk
ps_inbound_publications = mysql,asterisk
ps_asterisk_publications = mysql,asterisk
ps_transports = mysql,asterisk
ps_registrations = mysql,asterisk
```

***and my sorcery.conf is:***

```
[res_pjsip]
endpoint=realtime,ps_endpoints
auth=realtime,ps_auths
aor=realtime,ps_aors
contact=realtime,ps_contacts
domain_alias=realtime,ps_domain_aliases
;transport=realtime,ps_transports

[res_pjsip_endpoint_identifier_ip]
identify=realtime,ps_endpoint_id_ips

[res_pjsip_outbound_publish]
outbound-publish=realtime,ps_outbound_publishes

[res_pjsip_pubsub]
inbound-publication=realtime,ps_inbound_publications

[res_pjsip_publish_asterisk]
asterisk-publication=realtime,ps_asterisk_publications

[res_pjsip_outbound_registration]
registration=realtime,ps_registrations
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance